# How can I kill all stopped jobs?

Tags: linux, shell

When I try to exit from my Linux server I get the message:

There are stopped jobs.

: Is there a single command to kill these?

Comment: Additional examples in thie U&L Q&A: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124428/terminate-every-background-process

Comment: I had opposite problem now, it would not warn about stopped jobs when I quit the shell!  Had to put `shopt -s checkjobs` in my .bashrc

Comment: press ctrl + d again, it will let you exit now, killing those jobs in the process

Answer (score 124, accepted):

To quickly kill all the stopped jobs under the bash, enter:

```
kill -9 `jobs -ps`
```

`jobs -ps` lists the process IDs (`-p`) of the stopped (`-s`) jobs.
`` kill -9 `jobs -ps` `` sends SIGKILL signals to all of them.

Comment: didn't work when the job was "sudo su". i.e. `sudo kill \`jobs -p\`` didnt work but explicitly typing PID did.

Comment: Why is this upvoted so highly? It's wrong. If the processes are stopped, then a `kill` such as this will do nothing, since the processes are stopped, they won't process the SIGTERM (-15) that is sent to them by default.

Comment: kill -9 will do the trick.

Answer (score 90):

Try typing this:

```
kill -9 $(jobs -p)
```

Comment: That should do it, but I think he should send first a SIGTERM (-15) before sending a SIGKILL (-9). So perhaps proposing something like "kill $(jobs -p) ; sleep 3s ; kill -9 $(jobs -p)" would be better. Sending SIGTERM first the jobs may be able to do a clean exit (freeing allocated resources, etc).

Comment: Kevin Duke, your answer is the one that worked for me. I couldn't vote because I don't have 15 in reputation. kill -9 $(jobs -p)

Comment: @rems Except, as slm pointed out, they won't get the SIGTERM because they're stopped.

Comment: Does not work on zsh.  Due to [zsh not being POS](http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2006/msg00067.html) [IX compliant with jobs](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=346162).

Comment: Then, how to deal with zsh?

Answer (score 17):

The accepted answer would kill all jobs (which is sufficient in this case) and not merely the stopped ones. Should you want to kill only the Stopped ones, run:

```
kill $(jobs -l | grep Stopped | cut -d' ' -f3)
```

Comment: grep/cut can be combined in one awk command:  `awk '/Stopped/{print $3}')`

Comment: the `-s` argument on the accepted answer filters just the stopped ones

Answer (score 14):

The easiest way is actually to simply immediately retry the exit; `bash` will take that to mean "kill all stopped jobs and exit".

Comment: That will send a HUP which doesn't necessarily stop any jobs.

Answer (score 8):

```
for x in `jobs -p` ; do kill -9 $x ; done
```

Comment: you can add code formatting for this line to make it easier to read.

Comment: Can you take a look at your formatting again - use four spaces at the start of the line to mark a block as code (rather than using backtick).  Right now it isn't clear whether you are using backticks in your code, or trying to display code using backticks.

Comment: The formatting is fine. we have to pass the jobs -p using backticks else it wont consider as a command, and it will throw an error.

Answer (score 6):

Normally if you got that message, you need to logout twice. E.g. first <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> gives you the warning message to inform you about stopped jobs, pressing for the second time will log you out killing the jobs. This the same applies to `logout` and `exit` commands.

To kill them manually, try: `kill $(jobs -p)`.

---

If you don't want to kill jobs from your current shell, you can remove them from the table of active jobs without killing by using `disown` command. E.g.

```
$ sleep 1000 &
[1] 19404
$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 sleep 1000 &
$ disown
```

---

Stopped jobs also can be determined by the state of the process (`T` character) which means the process was stopped by signal such as `SIGSTOP`, `SIGTSTP` or other (like `SIGTTIN`, or `SIGTTOU`).

In case when `jobs` a shell builtin command is not available, stopped processes can be listed by the following command:

```
ps wuax | awk '$8 ~ "T"'
```

To kill them all, you can basically type:

```
kill -9 $(ps wuax | awk 'NR>1 && $8 ~ "T" {print $2}')
```

Here is a simple test:

```
$ sleep 1000 &
[1] 2014
$ sleep 1000 &
[2] 2015
$ sleep 1000 &
[3] 2016
$ sleep 1000 &
[4] 2017
$ killall -STOP sleep
[1]   Stopped                 sleep 1000
[2]   Stopped                 sleep 1000
[3]   Stopped                 sleep 1000
[4]   Stopped                 sleep 1000
$ ps wuax | awk '$8 ~ "T"'
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
vagrant   2014  0.0  0.0   7228   832 pts/0    T    20:38   0:00 sleep 1000
vagrant   2015  0.0  0.0   7228   708 pts/0    T    20:38   0:00 sleep 1000
vagrant   2016  0.0  0.0   7228   760 pts/0    T    20:38   0:00 sleep 1000
vagrant   2017  0.0  0.0   7228   828 pts/0    T    20:38   0:00 sleep 1000
$ kill -9 $(awk 'NR>1 && $8 ~ "T" {print $2}' <(ps wuax))
$ jobs
[1]   Killed                  sleep 1000
[2]   Killed                  sleep 1000
[3]   Killed                  sleep 1000
[4]   Killed                  sleep 1000
```

Answer (score 6):

Just in case this helps someone else -- most people are here because they have some stopped processes that they started, backgrounded via the shell maybe.  I needed to find processes, as root, stopped by other users, for which variants on the `jobs` command won't do.

A bit of digging around with `man ps` got me to this:

```
ps -a -o pid,user,cmd,state | grep 'T$'
```

Explanation:  the `-a` flag says show all processes, then `-o` controls output, what info will be shown about each process.  I'm choosing `pid`, `user`, `cmd` (the command line), and `state`, which is the *process state*.

From `man ps`:

```
PROCESS STATE CODES
   Here are the different values that the s, stat and state output specifiers (header "STAT" or "S") will display to describe the
   state of a process:
           D    uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
           R    running or runnable (on run queue)
           S    interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
           T    stopped, either by a job control signal or because it is being traced
           W    paging (not valid since the 2.6.xx kernel)
           X    dead (should never be seen)
           Z    defunct ("zombie") process, terminated but not reaped by its parent
```

so finally I pipe it to `grep T$` which says, show me all the processes that have T in the last column.

And then I have a nice list of all the processes from different users that are in the stopped state.

```
$ ps -a -o pid,user,cmd,state | grep 'T$'
  865 joson74+ python                      T
  885 joson74+ sh -c less                  T
  886 joson74+ less                        T
 1014 minames+ python3.4 -i /home/minames  T
 5352 MooKo    nano stdio.h                T
 7851 harry    tmux attach                 T
12083 harry    tmux attach                 T
13495 gorylla+ python3.4 -i /home/gorylla1 T
18009 conr1d   vim                         T
19664 enythin+ python                      T
24906 wardlist python                      T
```

Comment: To get stopped jobs attached to current shell, `jobs -ps` is simpler than this answer. That being said, this answer doesn't show only jobs stopped via `Ctrl-Z` in a shell, but **all stopped jobs: other shells, other users**, including jobs being debugged (e.g. by gdb).

Comment: For me the best answer, but not exactly working. I had to use `ps -el | grep T` to find the processes in state 'T'.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to remove some stopped jobs but not all, try this:

First, list jobs, you will get something like this:

```
$ jobs -l

[2]   4813 Stopped                 ./parse < call.txt
[3]-  4819 Stopped                 ./parse < call.txt
```

send kill to a stopped job, it will do nothing but queue
than bring it in in foreground, it will terminate

```
$ fg %2
./parse < call.txt
Terminated

$ jobs -l
[3]-  4819 Stopped                 ./parse < call.txt
```