# Why "jobs -p | kill -n 15" doesn't work?

Tags: linux, process, cygwin

I'm very new to Linux. And as a matter of fact I use Cygwin now and not Linux itself.

I'm trying to install [RVM](https://rvm.io) (Ruby Version Manager).

I was doing `rm -r ./.rvm -i` command. I wanted to remove `.rvm` folder and see how I'd been asked to delete or not a file/directory. I saw a few and stopped it with `Ctrl+Z` and then removed the whole `.rvm` folder with Windows Explored, just sent it to the recycle bin.

But when I wanted to exit the terminal with `exit` command I got a message that I had stopped jobs:

```
$ jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 rm -r ./.rvm -i
```

[Here](https://serverfault.com/a/240159/164562) I read how to kill the stopped job:

```
kill `jobs -p`
```

But I decided to try it with pipe command syntax I read about [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html#Pipelines):

> The output of each command in the pipeline is connected via a pipe to
>   the input of the next command

So I did these attempts but couldn't get the desired result:

```
$ jobs -p | kill
$ jobs -p | kill -n 15 # 15 is SIGTERM signal
$ jobs -p | kill -n=15 # got error wrong signal spec
$ jobs -p | kill -s SIGTERM
```

And I don't understand why it doesn't work. `jobs -p` lists process IDs:

```
$ jobs -p
340
```

So that `340` ID has to go to the `kill -n 15` command and it should kill the job. But it doesn't happen. Why? Is it possible to use pipe in this case?

Comment: Why not just `fg` the job? It does not answer your question, but it is one of the normals way to solve the 'you have stopped jobs' problem.

Comment: Just because I don't know `fg` command yet. Now I do :) Thanks.

Comment: In that case: you can background an already running process with control-Z, or a new process by adding an `&` behind the command. `jobs` should list these tasks. `fg` or `fg 1` will bring the first background process back. (If you have more jobs then you can add a number to select which process needs to be foregrounded).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Commands have several standard streams: Standard Out (stdout), Standard In (stdin), and Standard Error (stderr).
- Pipes send a command's stdout to another command's stdin
- Kill takes its paramters through its argument list, not any of the "standard" streams
- Some commands allow you to specify "-" on the argument to accept input from stdin as arguments (not the `kill` command)
- If you want to pipe stdout to another's argument list, you can use `xargs`, but care must be taken when there are potential spaces-- [and sometimes in other cases](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html)).

In your case, jobs -p shouldn't have any issues with xargs and you can use the following:

```
jobs -p | xargs kill
```

If you like, you can also see the exact commands it executes by using --verbose (or -t)

```
jobs -p | xargs --verbose kill
jobs -p | xargs -t kill
```

`xargs` is a powerful tool. Be very careful passing input to it (`find -print0`, `grep -Z`, and `xargs -0` get along well when working with files). Its well worth the effort to utilize it (and sometimes, time saved).

Answer (score 3):

`kill` doesn't take arguments from standard input, which is where they will appear if you pipe them as you have done.  The only way to use `kill` is to specify a PID, or list of PIDs, as command-line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

If SIGTERM (-15) does not work, then try SIGKILL (-9). It is recommended to try SIGTERM first though.

```
 kill `jobs -p`
 kill -9 `jobs -p`
```

Comment: Might want to add that using ` put the output of the jobs (in this case the PIDs on the command line. And not on std in/out.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can just type: fg, then hit ctrl-C.

In case you want to directly kill your remaining process, under bash, you can easily issue a:

```
kill %1
```

Which will kill the first process in background, as identified by jobs.

Comment: Could you explain why you find this a better alternative than the ones from '13 and already accepted?

Comment: Yes, there was a glitch: I meant: fg. Anyway, kill %1 will let you kill your first background process without having to find its PID.